# How to remove ubuntu server from laptop and install windows 7?

Tags: ubuntu

When trying to install Windows 7 via USB, I got stuck on choosing a disk to install, because I simply could not format them and just interact with them somehow through the Windows 7 installer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: When you are in the windows setup trying to choose a disk, switch to custom/advanced (can’t remember how it’s worded) and then delete all the existing partitions on the drive. Then click Next and windows will build new partitions and format them automatically. You just have to clear off the Linux partitions.